# Magnolia EE license auto deploy

Tags: docker, licensing, magnolia

I am trying to build an automatic deploy system for Magnolia 5.4 EE. For this, I exported the license config node `/config/modules/enterprise/license` to a file `config.modules.enterprise.license.xml` and attached this to the `mgnl-bootstrap/my-module`-directory of my module.

In this bootstrap-directory, other xml configuration files are present and are entered as expected into the configuration database. However, after deploy Magnolia still asks me to enter the license key - everything else works fine, my product is deployed, etc.

I tried to find information in the Magnolia documentation, but to no avail. Anyone here who was able to automatically deploy a Magnolia EE?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you add a dependency to `enterprise` magnolia module in your `my-module` descriptor file. This way the `enterprise` module will be installed before your module, and you just add a new node to its config. 
Another option is to add the license import file to `WEB-INF/bootstrap/common`, the difference here is that everything in that folder gets bootstrapped after *all* modules are started.